# A couple of questions about SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, vector-graphics

There are two questions about the SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics):

1) What is the best JavaScript library used to create vector graphics SVG?

2) Can I then received SVG vector graphics, the browser, export to a PDF file? If so, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your questions are already answered on Stackoverflow:

1. [Creating SVG graphics using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034712/creating-svg-graphics-using-javascript)
2. [Embedding SVG in PDF (exporting SVG to PDF using JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913338/embedding-svg-in-pdf-exporting-svg-to-pdf-using-js) or using java: [How to programmatically convert SVG to PDF on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048205/how-to-programmatically-convert-svg-to-pdf-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

About your first question, the best option I came across (and used heavily in a project) is [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/). I'm sure you will easily find a server-side solution to converting svg to pdf, but if you need to convert a Raphaël canvas into standard SVG data then [here's a plugin](https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.Export) wrote for exporting that data.